# How do I include my library on the page?

Tags: theming, javascript

I have an Angular app I want to use as a Drupal 8 theme but when I try to attach it with a YAML file, Drupal doesn't register that any JavaScript is being added to the theme.

ng.libraries.yml

```
base:
  version: 8.x
  css:
    css/styles.09e76a721be8ced0c439.bundle.css: {}
  js:
    js/inline.6375acbd4540ff168f58.bundle.js: {}
    js/polyfills.62cd0a749311c6ac36ca.bundle.js: {}
    js/vendor.d8949c111a4a3560f92d.bundle.js: {}
    js/vendor.d8949c111a4a3560f92d.bundle.js: {}
```

However, when I reference the script locations directly in my template, it works fine:

html.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html{{ html_attributes }}>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Hand of Death</title>
    <link href="themes/ng/dist/styles.09e76a721be8ced0c439.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="themes/ng/js/inline.cad96cf6be5b6cfb5176.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="themes/ng/js/polyfills.62cd0a749311c6ac36ca.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="themes/ng/js/vendor.d8949c111a4a3560f92d.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="themes/ng/js/main.665799e3572bc9816ad1.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

From what little I can make sense out of [the docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview), somewhere I'm going to have to call `Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior`, but that would not actually work in my situation.

Is there a way to get JavaScript to work without hardcoding it in the template?

**EDIT**: I've reverted this to the original so the corrections make sense to future users and went ahead and opened [a new question with the most recent code](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253246/how-do-i-include-my-library-on-the-page).

Comment: Not the same files: js/inline.6375acbd4540ff168f58.bundle.js vs inline.cad96cf6be5b6cfb5176.bundle.js - Those files seems to be dynamically generated, with varying filenames. Drupal libraries are for static files.

Comment: Thanks for catching that error. However, even when the libraries reference the static files, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

So you defined a custom library that includes CSS and JavaScript. This is done by creating the `ng.libraries.yml` file and adding the `base` library definition.

Next, you need to tell Drupal to include this library and [attach it to all the pages](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme#attach), if your `ng` theme is used for rendering the output. You can do so by adding a `libraries` section to your theme's `ng.info.yml` file:

```
libraries:
  - 'ng/base'
```

After clearing your caches, the library should be included.

Additionally, you may want to have a check for the syntax of the `.libraries.yml` file. CSS inclusion should follow the syntax:

```
css:
  theme:
    css/styles.09e76a721be8ced0c439.bundle.css: {}
```

Observe the `theme` part.

EDIT:

After you also added your `html.html.twig` template, another issue seems a missing js-bottom-placeholder tag. It will be replaced by any JavaScript that is not attached to the head region:

```
<js-bottom-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}">
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have given more detail. I've updated my post to include my ng.info.yml.

Comment: I added 'theme' under css but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Would you mind to also include your html.html.twig file without your hard-coded paths? Possibly the JS and CSS placeholders missing? Compare the core/themes/classy/templates/layout/html.html.twig file.

Comment: I updated it with html.html.twig

Answer (score 0):

You did just one part of the job, another part is adding your libraries to some pages or to all pages.

in `YOUR_THEME.info.yml` file add your defined library

```
libraries:
  - 'ng/base'
```

Part of Drupal Documentation about Attaching Libraries to a theme :

> **Attaching libraries to page(s)**: Some libraries you load may not be
>   needed on all pages. For faster performance don't load libraries where
>   they are not being used. Below are examples of how to selectively load
>   libraries.
>
> Attaching a library via a Twig template You can attach an asset
>   library to a Twig template using the attach_library() function in any
>   *.html.twig, file like so:
>
> {{ attach_library('fluffiness/cuddly-slider') }} Some fluffy
>   markup {{ message }} Attaching a library to all pages To attach
>   a library to all the pages that use your theme, declare it in your
>   theme's *.info.yml file, under the libraries key:

```
 name: Example 
 type: theme 
 core: 8.x 
 libraries:
   - fluffiness/cuddly-slider
```

List as many libraries as you want, all of them will be loaded on every page.

**After editing the *.info.yml or the *.libraries.yml file, remember to
 clear the cache so that the new information is loaded into Drupal.**

> Attaching a library to a subset of pages In some cases, you do not
>   need your library to be active for all pages, but just a subset of
>   pages. For example, you might need your library to be active only when
>   a certain block is being shown, or when a certain node type is being
>   displayed.
>
> A theme can make this happen by implementing a THEME_preprocess_HOOK()
>   function in the .theme file, replacing "THEME" with the machine name
>   of your theme and "HOOK" by the machine name of the theme hook.
>
> For instance, if you want to attach JavaScript to the maintenance
>   page, the "HOOK" part is "maintenance_page", and your function would
>   look like this:
>
> function fluffiness_preprocess_maintenance_page(&$variables) {
>   $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'fluffiness/cuddly-slider'; }
>   You can do something similar for other theme hooks, and of course your
>   function can have logic in it — for instance to detect which block is
>   being preprocessed in the "block" hook, which node type for the "node"
>   hook, etc.
>
> Important note! In this case, you need to specify the cacheability
>   metadata that corresponds to your condition! The example above works
>   unconditionally, so no cacheability metadata is necessary. The most
>   common use case is likely where you attach some asset library based on
>   the current route:
>
> ```
> function fluffiness_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
>   $variables['page']['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'route';
>   $route = "entity.node.preview";
>   if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() === $route) {
>     $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'fluffiness/node-preview';
>   }
> }
> ```

## I strongly recommend take a look at  [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme)

Comment: I've updated my question to include 'ng.info.yml'. I looked at the network requests, and the libraries successfully load, but nothing renders.

Comment: @MMBB would you please revert your changes and ask this in another question? if you change your question completely our answers not valid anymore and this means wasting time and efforts of others. also maybe in future, somebody has a problem like this and it might current answers help them. by the way, I'm here to help Drupalists.

Comment: I've gone ahead and opened a new question with the code as it stands now.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the bottom JS placeholder token in `html.html.twig`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html{{ html_attributes }}>
  <head>
    ...
    <js-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <js-bottom-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

Drupal has 2 different tokens for JS libraries: Usually it places all JS files at the end of the body, except you explicitly move them to the header in your libararies.yml.

Comment: Seems you have been faster than my editing. StackExchange via mobile isn't fun. ;)

Comment: I went back and added the second one but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Not according to your edit @MMBB. You used the same placeholder twice

Comment: @Clive thanks for that. I updated it but it's still not working. Neither is the CSS.

Comment: The CSS is still wrong too, you haven't added the `system`/`module`/`theme` key (see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/253250/2800)