# How do I include my libraries in a theme?

Tags: theming, javascript

This is a continuation of [a previous question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253246/how-do-i-include-my-library-on-the-page) I was asked to open as a new question with all of my changes incorporated. I'm trying to use an Angular front end as my theme, but despite following the docs, no GET requests are being made, so the files aren't being rendered.

ng.info.yml

```
name: ng
type: theme
base theme: classy
libraries:
  - ng/base
  - atlas/global-css
  - atlas/global-js
description: 'An theme that makes Angular do all the work'
core: 8.x
```

ng.libraries.yml (attempt 1)

```
base:
  version: 8.x
  css:
    dist/styles.bundle.css: {}
  js:
    dist/inline.bundle.js: {}
    dist/polyfills.bundle.js: {}
    dist/vendor.bundle.js: {}
    dist/main.bundle.js: {}
```

ng.libraries.yml (attempt 2)

```
base:
  version: 8.x
  css:
    theme:
      dist/styles.bundle.css: {}
  js:
    theme:
      dist/inline.bundle.js: {}
      dist/polyfills.bundle.js: {}
      dist/vendor.bundle.js: {}
      dist/main.bundle.js: {}
```

templates/html.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html{{ html_attributes }}>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Hand of Death</title>
    <!-- Set base href for Angular routing -->
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <meta name="description" content="A D.I.Y. record label for heavy music.">
    <css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}">
    <js-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <js-bottom-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

However, if I hardcode the the JavaScript and CSS into `html.html.twig`, the browser makes the GET request, succeeds, and the page renders fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in each of the libraries.yml attempts.

The first is missing the extra level for CSS. The second is adding an *extra* level to the JS, which shouldn't be there.

In either case the correct version is:

```
base:
  version: 8.x
  css:
    theme:
      dist/styles.bundle.css: {}
  js:
    dist/inline.bundle.js: {}
    dist/polyfills.bundle.js: {}
    dist/vendor.bundle.js: {}
    dist/main.bundle.js: {}
```

Other than that the code is fine (assuming the files are located at theme_name/dist/*); if your Angular app isn't working check the HTML source and see what's different between your static working version and the version in Drupal, and add some debugging code to the application.

Comment: I just tried that but it didn't work either. The difference between the static working version and the version that relies on Drupal is that Drupal doesn't inject the style and script tags. When I view the page source, the placeholder tags are gone, but there is nothing in their place.

Comment: Is the theme installed, enabled and active? Caches cleared?

Comment: Yeah. The theme works fine when the tags are hardcoded and I clear the cacheevery time I try something new.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what to tell you. I copy/pasted the above to be sure, works for me without any changes except for updating the theme name. I would start again, personally, and create a new theme which contains nothing but a single included library. If _that_ doesn't work, after following the docs to the letter, it's likely something is wrong with the core version of Drupal, contrib modules, or other custom code

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have implemented this in a technically correct way already, per the Drupal docs (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme) :

> In the case of front-end/styling (e.g. hosted font services), the JS
>   belongs in the theme. Put the JS directly in your html.html.twig file.
>   In the case of fonts, this will also allow you to put it right in the
>   place that gives you the best (and fastest) end user experience,
>   because it allows you to prevent a FOUT (Flash Of Unstyled Text) while
>   the font is still loading (fonts loaded through JS must be listed in
>   the HTML  before the CSS)!

Potentially you could also look at using a `hook_page_attachments_alter()` per the other Drupal.org article: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module:

> In the other case, the JS belongs in the module. In the appropriate
>   hook — likely hook_page_attachments() — define attached HTML 
>   data by using the 'html_head' key in the #attached property:

```
function fluffiness_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
    // The data.
    [
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      // The HTML tag to add, in this case a  tag.
      '#tag' => 'script',
      // The value of the HTML tag, here we want to end up with
      // alert("Hello world!");.
      '#value' => 'alert("Hello world!");',
      // Set attributes like src to load a file.
      '#attributes' => array('src' => ''),

    ],
    // A key, to make it possible to recognize this HTML  element when altering.
    'hello-world',
  ];
}
```